# TensorBuffer: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match

Tags: java

I am trying to display my Tensor Buffer on my app. It gives me this error saying the size and shape doesn't match:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Did you found any solution to the above question? As I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

first I need to ask you, did you use optimization when you convert the model to tfLite? if yes than you should read from here https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization. it is said that the optimize version is 4 times smaller so you need to create your byte buffer to [4 * 224 * 224 * 3] so it can match with the inputfeature0
and i dont know what kind of your input is it image or just data, if it image than you should resize it first

```
val resize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(*input image*, 256, 256, true)
```

I use bitmap for the images
that's based on my experience, hope that help